# Keeping navbar contents contained in center when stretching page

Tags: css

So im thinking i need to add the max-width property on my header. When i do, the content shifts to the left. I'm trying to have my navbar like instagram where it just stays centered even past the maxwidth. The max-width seems to work but my header sticks to the left when i stretch my page instead of staying centered. Any css pros out there?

My css

```
.container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.header__left {
  align-items: center;
}

.header__left__link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header__left__logo {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Kirang Haerang";
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.header__mid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__right__login {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__right__logout {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

My Header component

```
export const Header: React.FC<HeaderProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="header">
        <div className="header__left">
          <Link className="header__left__link" to="/">
            <h1 className="header__left__logo">Logo</h1>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="header__mid">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <div className="header__right">
          <h1 className="header__right__login">Login</h1>
          <h1 className="header__right__logout">Logout</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please also pro use the corresponding HTML

Comment: My best guess for you issue is to change: `justify-content: space around;` to `justify-content: center;`. Alternativly use `media queries` to  add a breakpoint.

Comment: @tacoshy my fault guys i shoulve specified that this is a react project. Should i still show you my html or my header component

Comment: yes for the next time. then also flag it with the reactjs tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is very difficult to help without seeing the html code also.
But if all else fails, you could possibly try to use

```
margin: auto 25%;
```

And just play with the number until the element is where you want it.

Comment: **down-voted for following reason:** This is a very broad and vague answer to an unclear question. Such questions should be commented not answered until the questions was edited to add more clarity. Also it is technical incorrect. To center block level elements you use `margin: auto;` for `left` and `right` not for `top` and `bottom`. As such your syntax is wrong (but also not needed at all for flexbox).

Comment: @tacoshy I know what `margin: auto` is normally used for. I only added `auto` because I didn't know if ts had any margin for top or bottom. So it is basically just a filler meant to do nothing other than show possible top-bottom margin. Therefore it is technically not incorrect. It's just not the best solution. Furthermore, the question was not unclear to me. It was just lacking more code to help others help with the problem. I just wanted to try and help anyway so ts (and others at stackoverflow) possibly didn't have to spend more time on this problem. And I did help, as you can see.

Comment: @HelpANoobOut Amazing! I am glad I could be of assistance ^^